# If you have $3$ different types of Cans ; How many ways can you choose $5$ cans?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> If you have $3$ different types of Cans ; How many ways can you choose $5$ cans?

Solution (1)

The first Can can be chosen from $3$ types :$3$

The second Can can be chosen from $3$ types :$3$

And so on ... so the answer =$3^{5}$

Solution  (2)
By Star's and Bar's Method

$x+y+z=5$

$(5+3-1)C5=7C5$

Which solution  is the right one?  Please explain it to me

Answer (score 2):

Stars and bars will lead to the correct solution here; the areas cordoned off by the bars represent the number of cans of a particular type taken.

Notably your first solution is not correct, as you could pick $$1, 2, 1, 2, 1$$ and then $$2, 2, 1, 1, 1$$; which should be counted only once.

Answer (score 1):

Your **first method** is incorrect. You are just choosing $5$ cans. So the order in which you choose cans does not matter. Suppose you choose $ABABC$, or $AABBC$. These two are identical choices. In the first method, you are counting both as separate cases.

In your **second method**, you are counting these cases only once. So it is more suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the exponent answer and the stars and bars answer is whether the *order* of the cans matter: are you putting them neatly in a row, or throwing them into a bag? So they're both right, depending on how you read the question.

I would favour the stars and bars interpretation in this case, but the question is ambiguous. It is only because I've read a lot of problems like this, and I expect the problem author has too that I can say that stars and bars is probably the right way to go, based on the way the question is phrased.