# How many different collections of cans can be formed from three different types of cans?

Tags: combinatorics

We are on the additional and multiplication principles section of the book (haven't gotten to permutations and combinations yet) and I have this question and I don't even know where to start.

> How many different collections of cans can be formed from five identical Coca-Cola (C) cans, four identical Seven-Up (S) cans, and seven identical Mountain Dew (M) cans?

Usually the questions tell you how many you'll pick (like in this example [If you have $3$ different types of Cans ; How many ways can you choose $5$ cans?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460398/if-you-have-3-different-types-of-cans-how-many-ways-can-you-choose-5-cans)) but this one is open ended. Can the collection only be one can or two cans? Can it be the same type of cans?

I was thinking it could be something like $C=5$, $S=4$, and $M=7$. And you find different possibilities and add them together.

$5\cdot4\cdot7 + 5\cdot4 + 5\cdot7+4\cdot7+5+4+7 =239$

Comment: Is one can a collection, or indeed no cans at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost right, except that you forgot to consider the empty collection of cans, which brings the total number to $240$. Another way to get to the same result is the following argument: a combination of cans is uniquely determined by the number of cans of each type: so you have $6$ possibilities for the Coca-Cola type (namely, you can pick $0$, $1$,..., or $5$ cans), and similarly $5$ possibilities for the Seven-Up and $8$ for the Mountain Dew. So in total you'll have $6\cdot 5\cdot 8=240$ possible combinations of cans.